# Imprimir Suma de Objetos almacenado en ArrayList en JAVA

Tags: java, arraylist, objeto, agregación

Me dejaron un ejercicio sobre orden y producto(agregacion), y no se como sumar Objetos almacenados en un ArrayList eh intentado varias cosas como convertir el objeto a double pero el resultado siempre es lo mismo, si alguien sabe como hacerlo seria de mucha ayuda gracias.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Orden {
    private static int contador;
    private int IdOrden;
    private ArrayList<Object> productos = new ArrayList<>();
    private double total;
    
    public int getIdOrden() {
        return IdOrden;
    }
    public Orden() {
        this.IdOrden = ++contador;
    }   
    public void agregarProducto(Object producto) {
        try {
            productos.add(producto);    
            
        }catch(Exception e) {
            String errMsg = e.getMessage();
            System.out.println(errMsg);
        }   
    }

    public double calcularTotal() {         
        total = 0;      
        for (Object i:productos) {
            System.out.println(i.toString());
            total += i.precio;          
            }   
        return total;   
    }
    public void mostrardatos() {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("ID_Orden :" + IdOrden);
        calcularTotal();
        System.out.println("Total :" + total);              
    }   
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

me imprime esto y lo que deseo es sumar los precios y imprimirlo en total

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: pone un println de i.precio dentro de la funcion calcularTotal y fijate que los valores sean correctos. Todo esto dentro del for.

Comment: Ya lo probe pero igual sale error (Precio cannot be resolved or is not a field) Son dos clases que tengo (aggregate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si vas a trabajar con los objetos de clase `Producto` no necesitas hacer referencia a la clase `Object` te ahorras el tener que hacer un cast

```
 private ArrayList<Producto> productos = new ArrayList<>();

 public void agregarProducto(Producto producto) {
```

El tipo de retorno de un método se especifica en la declaración del método. Dentro del cuerpo del método, se utiliza la sentencia `return` para devolver el valor.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en tu caso tu caso tu método `calcularTotal` devuelve un `double` y solo debería realizar esa tarea calcular el total de precios de los productos, no incluyas un print mas para un uso de debug

```
 public double calcularTotal() {         
        total = 0;      
        for (Producto i:productos) {
             total +=i.getPrecio();          
            }   
        return total;   
    }
```

como el método anterior devuelve un valor esperado debes imprimir ese valor y no la variable precio que esta declarada como 0

```
  public void mostrardatos() {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("ID_Orden :" + IdOrden);
        for (Producto i:productos ) {
            System.out.println(i.toString());
        }
        System.out.println("Total :" + calcularTotal());              
    }
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias!! por la solución y por resolverme las dudas que tenia,

Comment: Me alegra poder haberte ayudado, te invito a realizar el respectivo [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y de paso ver como realizar una [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) mejor recibida,para una proxima ,tu código debe adjuntarse como texto y no como imagen :) saludos y bienvenid@!!

Comment: Okey gracias por los tips.